# I'm having trouble using a class I have created in another class in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a Clock program in java. I have a counter class that takes two parameters, an initial value(integer) and a limit(also an integer). I have another class, a Clock class, which ought to have two parameters (hour and minutes). And this parameters are supposed to be objects of the counter class. How do I create an instance of the counter class in the clock class

Comment: I suggest reading this chapter to better understand the concept. (Objects and Classes)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Call `new` and assign the reference to a variable, of course.

Something like this:

```
public class Clock {
    private Counter counter;

    public Clock(int hour, int minutes) {
        // don't know what you want here.  Can't see how they're related.
        this.counter = new Counter(0, 60*hour+minutes);
    } 
}
```

Comment: `new Counter(hour, minutes)` -- really? Take a look at the problem statement again.  This will only confuse the OP, who is operating at beginner level.

Comment: Thanks duffymo, but the hour and minutes parameters are supposed to be counters.

Comment: I'm not going to read your mind.  I can show you how to create a Counter in a Clock.  you figure out the rest.

Comment: OK, duffymo. That'll be fine

Comment: The OP has not specified, but one can deduce that `Clock` will need two `Counter` objects.  One has an initial value of zero and a limit of 23 (hours) and the other has an initial value of zero and limit of 59 (minutes).  The OP must decide if the limit is inclusive or exclusive (23 or 24, for instance)... in Java it should be exclusive (i.e. 24), and how to handle rollover and carry from one to the other.  Also, I suspect by "initial value" the OP really means "lower limit".

Comment: Has not specified.  My implementation will count down as many minutes as the input parameters call for.  Good enough.  Only one Counter needed.

Comment: A link was sent to me, and from what you guys have said and the information I've gotten I think I've solved my problem. But there's another one.